# Asynchronous texture loading and sharegroups in OpenGL ES 2.0 and iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, asynchronous, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to create a GLKView where I add cubes and draw them. The problem is, each cube is of type NSObject and has its own vertex and texture buffers but I want to draw them in a single context. In order to do this, I followed some WWDC videos and created two contexts, one for rendering and one for texture loading, and I put both into the same sharegroup. Code-wise what I did in this respect, was adding a property called renderContext to my GLKView, which I want all cubes to be drawn in and I also set up a loaderContext property, where I want to load textures. However, nothing is drawn at all, I do not see anything, and sometimes I get a crash and GL ERROR 0x0500. It used to work and model view matrix should be setup correctly and everything. The introduction of the asynchronous loading and the two shared contexts caused the problem...

Here is the code:

**This is the GLKView: Container(containing the cubes)**

```
- (void)setupGL {

    self.renderContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
    self.loaderContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2 sharegroup:self.renderContext.sharegroup];

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &defaultFrameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, defaultFrameBuffer);

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

}



- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {


    self.opaque = NO;

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.renderContext];

    for(Cube *cube in self.cubes){

        [cube draw];

    }


}
```

**Each individual cube is set up like this:**

```
-(id)init {


    self = [super init];
    if(self){        

        self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc]init];
        self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(45.0f,0.95f, 0.1f, 2.0f);
        self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix, 0, 0.0, 0.0);
        self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix,0,0,-1.3);


        glGenBuffers(1, &vertexArray);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArray);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);

        glGenBuffers(1, &texArray);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texArray);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(TexCoords), TexCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,0);


    }

    return self;




}
```

**And has a draw method:**

```
-(void)draw{


    [self.effect prepareToDraw];

    self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = YES;


    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){

        if(i==0)glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, frontTexture.name);
        if(i==1)glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, rightTexture.name);
        if(i==2)glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, backTexture.name);
        if(i==3)glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, leftTexture.name);
        if(i==4)glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, bottomTexture.name);
        if(i==5)glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, topTexture.name);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, i*6, 6);
    }



}
```

Here is how I try to asynchronously load textures:

Note: The GLKView (container) is the parent of each individual cube, whose loaderContext I retrieve, which is in the renderContext's sharegroup, so textures should be drawn correctly, right ?

```
-(void)loadTextureForTexture:(GLKTextureInfo*)texN withView:(CubeView *)cV{

    __block GLKTextureInfo *texName = texN;

    EAGLContext *loaderContext = self.parent.loaderContext;
    self.textureLoader = [[GLKTextureLoader alloc]initWithSharegroup:loaderContext.sharegroup];
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:loaderContext];

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft];

    dispatch_queue_t loaderQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();



    [self.textureLoader textureWithCGImage:[self imageWithView:cV].CGImage options:options queue:loaderQueue completionHandler:^(GLKTextureInfo *tex, NSError *err){

        texName = tex;

        if(err)
            NSLog(@"%@", err);
        else
            NSLog(@"no error");

        dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^{

            [self display];

        });

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you’re doing more context management than is necessary:

- `GLKTextureLoader` only needs to know which `EAGLSharegroup` to create its textures in. You don’t have to create an `EAGLContext` on its behalf, and the one you’re creating in your code already isn’t being passed into any `GLKTextureLoader` methods.
- You should not manually need to manage the current `EAGLContext`—in fact, the documentation for `GLKView` specifically mentions that you should not change the current context from inside your drawing methods.

The net result of this is that other than extracting the `EAGLSharegroup` from your existing context for `GLKTextureLoader` creation, you should have no new context management code.

Additionally, it looks like the result of loading the texture never makes it out of `loadTextureForTexture:withView:`. Your `texN` variable is not passed into the function by reference, so `texName` is only visible to `loadTextureForTexture:withView:` and your texture loading completion block. Once `loadTextureForTexture:withView:` returns and your completion block is invoked, the data is gone. It seems like there should be some kind of `CubeView` setter that needs to be called with the `GLKTextureInfo *` you’ve received.

Comment: Thank you so much Pivot, this helped me tremendously !!! However, there is still a problem with asynchronous drawing. If I call the `-display` method asynchronously, the application crashes, if I do it synchronously, it works.

Comment: How are you trying to trigger asynchronous display? It seems like you should be asynchronously calling `setNeedsDisplay` on your view from the main queue.

Comment: What does setNeedsDisplay do exactly in a GLKView ? When I call display I do exactly what you see above in my code. I am actually calling `-display` on the container (the GLKView) which basically goes through all the cubes (NSObjects) and draws them within the delegate method of the GLKView which is `- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect `

Comment: Are you making these calls to the main thread/dispatch queue? It is unsafe to interact with `UIView`s (including `GLKView`) off the main thread.

Comment: I made the decision not to continue to use Apple's GLKit classes as they are still very buggy and they simply freak me out. It caused a lot of problems up to now, so I figured I should roll it out without it. And it works brilliantly right now. But thank you anyway, I hope this answer will help others in the future. Have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 0):

First problem I see in your code is absence of color attachment to the renderbuffer, so you only get depth output which would not draw anything.

```
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorBuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA4, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer);
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I am relatively sure that the absence of a color buffer is not the culprit of the problem, because it used to work before without one. If my code was correct, I would see the textures, or, in the case of an absence of textures, black cubes... But I just do not see anything, which is utterly weird...